# Chrome.runtime.onMessage doesn't work to send message from popup to content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I my Chrome extension, I have a `button` in my `popup.html` (that appears in the top-right toolbar). The `popup.html` file is linked to a `HTMLjs.js` file which has the following code:

```
(function(){
    window.onload = init;

    function init(){            
        button.onclick = function(){

            console.log("Working onclick!"); // working!

            // send the message to the content script
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(["testing"]); 
        }
    }
})();
```

And the content script, has the following code:

```
 (function () {
     window.onload = init;

         // when receiving the message from html popup.html
         chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, MessageSender, sendReponse) {
             // Sender MessageSender: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender
             // function sendResponse: needed to send response, not needed in current context (?)

             console.log(message); // not work
             console.log("W"); // not work
             alert("W"); // not work
             sendReponse(); // not work

             return true;
         });
     }
 })();
```

I have both the consoles open (the stackoverflow webpage's and the `popup.html`'s), and only the `console.log("Working onclick!");` works. It appears that the message is not at all received by the content-script.

Here's the [manifest.json](http://hastebin.com/sefatajodu.xml) if it matters.

### UPDATE:

Using the accepted answer, I needed:

```
// get the active tab, and send its id along with message using tabs.sendMessage
chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs){
    // send the message to the content script
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, ["testing"]);               
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a message to a content script, you need to use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage).